# GET request on my form and UTF-8

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, utf-8

I have a problem with GET request on my form and UTF-8.
UTF-8 and arabic character work fine in my web application developed by `spring mvc + hibernate` except with Get request in my form (post request work fine)

```
<form:form method="get" .... >
```

in controller i got character like this `ÙÙØ³Ù`

I read that i have to put `URIEncoding="UTF-8" on <Connector> in server.xml` i try it when i deploy my project and it's work but with eclipse i can't found this file because i'm in developing level, even when i add this line in `server.xml` in tomcat directory but tomcat in eclipse seems not be affected with these changes even if i change the http port !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved i was editing the wrong file, actually in eclipse the file `server.xml` can be found in **Servers** section in **Projects explorer**
Because eclipse use a tomcat instance not the original tomcat.
So you have to add `URIEncoding="UTF-8" on <Connector> in server.xml` and the **get** request work fine with arabic character.